# Computing determinant and using division and multiplication of uint64_t C type

Tags: c, int64, uint64

This question has been edited to clarify it.

I have the following matrix, defined in page 1 of [reteam.org/papers/e59.pdf], written in R notation:

```
m1 = matrix(c(207560540,956631177,1,956631177,2037688522,1,2037688522,1509348670,1),ncol=3,byrow=T)
```

The determinant of m1 should be a integer multiple of 2^31 -1.

As indicated in accepted answer, det(m1) should be -1564448852668574749.

However, in R, I got

```
> det(m1)
[1] -1564448852668573184
```

and, using a simple equation by hand:

```
> m1[1,1]*(m1[2,2]-m1[3,2]) - m1[2,1]*(m1[1,2] - m1[3,2]) + m1[3,1]*(m1[1,2]- m1[2,2])
[1] -1564448852668574720
```

As indicated in accepted answer, the correct determinant is obtained 
and checked by:

```
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

int64_t m1[3][3] = {{INT64_C(207560540) , INT64_C(956631177)   , INT64_C(1)},{ INT64_C(956631177), INT64_C(2037688522),       INT64_C(1)},{INT64_C(2037688522), INT64_C(1509348670) ,   INT64_C(1)}};                                                         

int64_t dm1 = m1[0][0]*(m1[1][1]-m1[2][1]) - m1[1][0]*(m1[0][1] - m1[2][1]) + m1[2][0]*(m1[0][1]- m1[1][1]);
int64_t divisor = (INT64_C(1)<<31) -1;
int64_t tmp = dm1/divisor;
int64_t check = tmp * divisor;

printf("dm1 == %" PRIu64"\n",dm1);
printf("(dm1/(2^31 -1))* %" PRIu64 " == %" PRIu64 "\n", divisor, check);
```

}

The following text is the old question. The main error was using a unsigned type.

---

My old minimum non-working code example was:

```
  #include <inttypes.h>
  #include <stdio.h>

  int main() {

  uint64_t dm1 = 1564448852668573184;
  uint64_t divisor = (UINT64_C(1)<<31) -1; //powl(2,31)-1;
  uint64_t tmp = dm1/divisor;
  uint64_t check = tmp*divisor;                                                                                      

  printf("dm1 == %" PRIu64"\n",dm1);
  printf("(dm1/(2^31 -1))* %" PRIu64 " == %" PRIu64 "\n", divisor, check);
}
```

Its output is

```
dm1 == 1564448852668573184

(dm1/(2^31 -1))* 2147483647 == 1564448850521091102
```

The problem is that the value of the second line should be equal to the one in the first line.

What is my mistake? How can I make this work?

Comment: Note: `uint64_t divisor = (UINT64_C(1) << 31) - 1;`

Comment: @Olaf How does that differ from `uint64_t divisor = 1; divisor = (divisor <<31)-1;`?

Comment: Use hex notation. There seems to be a truncation problem.

Comment: Because it does not divide exactly, it has a remainder. Integer division truncates.

Comment: @chux: That's why I used "Note:". I did not state the original is incorrect. It just is easier to comprehend

Comment: @Olaf: I tried hex notation and result is the same.

Comment: How can the result be the same if you have a different base output? Do the calculation by hand.

Comment: @WeatherVane: I got this number 1564448852668573184 from section 2 [reteam.org/papers/e59.pdf]. I computed the determinant dm1 of the first matrix in there. The author says this is to be an integer multiple of 2^31 -1.

Comment: The number `1564448852668573184` does not appear in the paper you quoted. My calculator says it does not divide exactly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The numerator is not an exact multiple of the divisor, so there is a remainder, and the quotient is truncated.

```
1564448852668573184 / 2147483647 = 728503266 remainder 2147482082
```

Multiplying back,

```
2147483647 * 728503266 + 2147482082 = 1564448852668573184
```

**EDIT:**

The determinant of the 3x3 matrix shown in your linked reference is `-1564448852668574749`. This is exactly divisible by `2147483647` to give `-728503267`.

So you have an arithmetic overflow somewhere.

**ANSWER:**

The value of the matrix determinant in your linked example is negative. Please use `int64_t` instead of `uint64_t`.

Comment: I got this number 1564448852668573184 from section 2 [reteam.org/papers/e59.pdf]. I computed the determinant dm1 of the first matrix in there. The author says this is to be an integer multiple of 2^31 -1.

Comment: The number `1564448852668573184` does not appear in the paper you quoted. My calculator says it does not divide exactly.

Comment: No it doesn't appear. I computed it by the determinant from the matrix appearing in the first page.

Comment: Before I was computing determinant outside C. Here is now  how I compute: `uint64_t m1[3][3] = {{UINT64_C(207560540) , UINT64_C(956631177)   , UINT64_C(1)},{ UINT64_C(956631177),                       UINT64_C(2037688522),   UINT64_C(1)},{UINT64_C(2037688522), UINT64_C(1509348670) ,   UINT64_C(1)}};`  This results in determinant  dm1=16882295221040976867 which still is not multiple of 2^31 -1. I suspect I have overflow problems while computing my determinant.

Comment: Use `int64_t` not unsigned. The values just fit the range,

Comment: @WeatherVane DO NOT use `int64_t`, signed integer overflow is UB in C

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux What can I use instead of int64_t to avoid UB?

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux did you downvote? The signed arithmetic did not overflow. That is how I found the determinant and I checked it with a bigint library too. The sum of the positive terms is `3816150093823856864` and the (positive) sum of the negative terms is `5380598946492431613`. Neither overflows 64 bit signed int.

Comment: @MarcKees just ignore him. He is wrong in this case, but with larger numbers you'd need a big int library. I was proving the point that your determinant calculation was in error.

Comment: @WeatherVane Before I thought this would be a good question. However thanks to you, now I understand what happened. It seems my question does not make sense anymore. Should I delete it?

Comment: Please don't delete it. I answered your problem by saying you used unsigned instead of signed, when the result is negative. Regardless of the size of the operands, this is true.

Comment: @WeatherVane it might be ok for this particular data nput, but when there is a general expression which could overflow NEVER use signed integers, code would be undefuned

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux it's not a general expression, it was a particular expression for this particular problem, which solved it. So what type would you suggest? Should I use your all-embracing type on every calculation, since you say I must never use signed arithmetic? Do you imply that unsigned arithmetic is ok? I know its wrapping is legal, but that does not prevent it giving a wrong amswer.

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux good grief. I am struggling to take you seriously. We all know that arithmetic can overflow. This doesn't.

Comment: @WeatherVane the stated problem is integer matrix DETERMINANT calculation. This is wrong kind of advice for determinant calculation to switch to integer type which could cause UB in case of overflow - pure and simple. Dixi!

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux you haven't even said what data type you would use. Please explain how, if `double`, when the significance exceed 63 bits, the modulus could be a whole number? Come on, post a better answer or undo the downvote!

Comment: @MarcKees I briefly looked into paper - you need integer math, so use of doubles is pretty much no-no. Either continue with with `uint64_t` with explicit overflow control, or something like GNU MP.

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux OP did not use `double`. And `uint64_t` was the cause of his troubles, because he needed a signed type. Please get up to speed. My answer uses integer math. I ask again, what would you have done? You are talking utter nonsense.

Answer (score 0):

For the same reason that (using integers) you get `10 / 3 * 3 = 9`. There is a remainder of the division. `10 / 3 = 3`, with remainder `1`. When you multiply by `3`, the remainder is lost, so you get `9` instead of `10`.

In this case, your remainder is `2147482082`, which, when added to `1564448850521091102`, gives `1564448852668573184`. Try this:

```
uint64_t dm1 = 1564448852668573184;
uint64_t divisor = (UINT64_C(1)<<31) -1; //powl(2,31)-1;
uint64_t tmp = dm1/divisor;
uint64_t remainder = dm1%divisor;
uint64_t check = tmp*divisor+remainder;
```

And you should get the correct result.